# Composer Undefined variable: auth

Tags: php, capistrano, composer-php

I'm getting the error 'undefined variable: auth' Running composer via Capistrano.
Here id the stack trace when running cap deploy -d

```
--> Updating Composer dependencies..........................Preparing to execute     command: "sh -c 'cd /path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437 && SYMFONY_ENV=livetest /usr/bin/php composer.phar update -vvv --prefer-dist'"
Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|  
✘
*** [err :: server] [ErrorException]
*** [err :: server] Undefined variable: auth
*** [err :: server] 
*** [err :: server] 
*** [err :: server] 
*** [err :: server] Exception trace:
*** [err :: server] () at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437   /composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/Git.php:133
*** [err :: server] Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/Git.php:133
*** [err :: server] Composer\Util\Git->runCommand() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/Vcs/GitDriver.php:80
*** [err :: server] Composer\Repository\Vcs\GitDriver->initialize() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:86
*** [err :: server] Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->getDriver() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/VcsRepository.php:113
*** [err :: server] Composer\Repository\VcsRepository->initialize() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:170
*** [err :: server] Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:100
*** [err :: server] Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:387
*** [err :: server] Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:224
*** [err :: server] Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:134
*** [err :: server] Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
*** [err :: server] Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
*** [err :: server] Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
*** [err :: server] Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
*** [err :: server] Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
*** [err :: server] Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
*** [err :: server] Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
*** [err :: server] require() at /path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437/composer.phar:25
*** [err :: server] 
*** [err :: server] 
*** [err :: server] update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]     [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
Preparing to execute command: "rm -rf /path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437; true"
Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|  
failed: "env PHP_PATH=/usr/bin/php sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /path/to/site/public_html/releases/20141223155437 && SYMFONY_ENV=livetest /usr/bin/php composer.phar update -vvv --prefer-dist'\\'''" on server
```

Capifony downloads a new build of composer each time so this error would be coming from the latest build.
Anyone know what this could be?

EDIT: Composer file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.0.*@dev",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "pagerfanta/pagerfanta": "1.0.*@dev",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "v2.3.7",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle":"1.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
}
```

I've removed some private repos

Composer version:

```
Composer version 1.0-dev (4569f528f66739ec0a3be1075e2c01d6062b0b41) 2014-12-22 11:50:02
```

Comment: Please add your composer.json to the question and provide the composer version.

Comment: I've updated the question with the composer.json and the version

Comment: Aha It was the missing credentials for the private repos. Its now working again.

Comment: Please create a little answer from that finding and place it below. You can accept it then (this is accepted practice, you're welcome to answer your own questions). Thanks!

Comment: @pfwd Can you please update your question with the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was missing the credentials  for the private repository. 
The credentials need to be set like so:

```
 :repository,     "https://username@example.com/path/to/repo"
```

Comment: How can I set them? I'm trying to use this with Heroku: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31686568/1399706

Comment: Can you explain where you added the credentials? Been struggling with this for a while now

Comment: Updated answer. Hope this helps