# How to provide access to a git repository that is used by Composer

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, ssh, composer-php

To manage my libraries I use Composer, so I set the dependencies in `composer.json` and then add (ever in `composer.json`) the remote addresses of the private repositories where the code resides.

When running `composer update/install` I'm prompted with a request for the access keys to those private repository.

Now, I'm trying to deploy a Symfony 2 app to Heroku.

**The problem arises when Heroku tries to download the packages from my private repositories: how can I provide to Heroku access to those repositories?**

Here is a sample composer.json configuration:

```
"require": {
    "my/private-package": "~1.0",
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://Aerendir@bitbucket.org/Aerendir/private-package"
    }
]
```

This configuration [is explained in the Composer Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#setup) (it works also without Satis, except for the "problem" with Heroku :) - or other cloud hosting I think).

There, about athentication, is explained:

> Note that if your private packages are hosted on GitHub, your server
>   should have an ssh key that gives it access to those packages, and
>   then you should add the --no-interaction (or -n) flag to the command
>   to make sure it falls back to ssh key authentication instead of
>   prompting for a password. This is also a good trick for continuous
>   integration servers.

Now, the questions are 2:

1. BitBucket has [deployment keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys) but I can also [set a SSH key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).
2. What
   about [Heroku SSH keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku)?

**So, how can i give to Heroku access to my private repositories on BitBucket?**
**How can I download private repositories hosted on BitBucket from the `composer install` command that Heroku does on deploying?**

Comment: You probably want a deployment key added to Bitbucket (the public part) and use it in Heroku (the private part).

Comment: Can you tell me more, please?

Comment: @Aerendir did you ever solve this issue??? or did you give up on using heroku? lol ... thanks

Comment: I solved using a third-party service called GemFury...

Comment: thank you ... i was hoping to accomplish it using a key pair...

Comment: It is really faster to use a service like the one I use... I knw it isn't the best solution, but for the moment I need to go online, so this is the only way... But I'll came back on the problem and hope I'll find a solution...

Comment: moved it to an ec2 instance... I have learned not to use something for what its NOT intended for (PHP) ...

Comment: Can you reply to my question explaining your solution? Anyway the service I use is intended to do this... But i'm curious about your solution, as I prefer to maintain the privacy of my code...

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-deployment-keys-294486051.html ...

but that does require you to generate or at least be able to move a current pair of keys to the server that's making the request... 

i think the best solution is to resolve and download your deps in development or staging... then create a .zip or .tar of the /vendor directory then just include it in the server image... 

Because i dont think heroku allows you to upload a key to any perticular container...

Comment: No, infact, Heroku doesn't allow to upload a key pair... For this reason the only solution is a private composer server. As to set up one is a sensitive and complex task, I chose to use a third party service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is using `COMPOSER_AUTH` as an environment variable set directly in Heroku dashboard.

The value of the variable should be something like this:

```
{
   "http-basic":{
      "bitbucket.org":{
         "username":"hello@aerendir.me",
         "password":"y0UrH4rdT0Gu3sSp4SsW0rd"
      }
   }
}
```

If set, Composer will read it and use its value to connect to BitBucket.

This is the correct approach as it is secure and doesn't force you to make your passwords going around in the web through the various services you use (or will use) to build and deploy your app.

References:

[`COMPOSER_AUTH`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-auth)

Comment: Downside is the plaintext password.

Comment: You have to set it in plaintext somewhere... Until you use an API key, but in that case your API key is anyway in plaintext and can be stolen...

It is a responsibility of yours ensure security of env variables...

Answer (score -1):

to make https works with composer

1. you should create auth token in bitbucket.
2. run `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com token`

or

add server ssh key to bitbucket

and change
`https://bitbucket.com/organisation/reponame.git`

to

`git@bitbucket.com:organisation/reponame.git`

hope it helps

Comment: what is the server ssh key in heroku?

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer by editing it. How does all this work if the configuration is run on a cloud server?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved/circumvented this limitation of Heroku of using Composer to install dependencies in private BitBucket repositories by:

changing:

```
git@bitbucket.org:username/repository.git
```

in my composer.json to:

```
https://bitbucket.org/username/repository.git
```

When running `composer update --no-dev`, Composer will ask you for the username / password combination to authenticate. Next Composer will offer you to save these credentials in `/Users/username/.composer/auth.json`, also see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md

Choose "Y" to have that file created.

Now copy the created `auth.json` to your project folder. Use git to add, commit and push it to Heroku.

This worked for me, unfortunately the `auth.json` stores your password in plain text, so for me it is not an ideal solution...

Somebody from Heroku monitoring this issue? When using http://www.CloudControl.com one can inspect the details of an application, which includes a public key. Add that to BitBucket and it works. Either that or have Composer properly use the public keys one can add to Heroku...

### UPDATE: directly in composer.json

Another option is to (simply) include a section in the `composer.json` file which is used by Heroku to install the dependencies.

```
"bitbucket-oauth": {
  "bitbucket.org": {
    "consumer-key": "key-goes-here",
    "consumer-secret": "secret-goes-here"
  }
}
```

Also see

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#bitbucket-oauth

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181522/1399706 Your approach is really wrong and dangerous! You need to use the environment variables!

Comment: You are correct, and I mention that this solution is not ideal. In 2016 the approach with the environment variable did not exist yet. 

So please all, do not use my suggested approach!